# SQL : How to search for a text field

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have table where one column of it holds the content of a xml file. Among these xml files, some contains text HASH_VALUE. i want to find out rows which are having xml files with the text HASH_VALUE. i tried to use `like(%HASH_VALUE%)` but this does not retrieve any row

could anybody explain me how to do this.

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Inside the XML you want to find the text ? It's mean you need to scan the XML files open them,search,if found put the XML in folder if no, keep scan, this is what you mean?

Comment: I don't want this manual process. I am trying to write sql query to select rows which are having xml filed and xml file content has HASH_VALUE text field

Comment: What does the xml column hold? an XML string or a reference to a file ? what is the type of the column ?

Comment: xml string. type of the column is CLOB

Comment: Maybe put in Col aside the hash value of each XML.

Comment: @KItis, strange that it returned *no rows*, I would expect an `ORA-00911: invalid character`, since you need to use `'` instead of `(`

Comment: can it be because of the data type? CLOB

Comment: @KItis is the string HASH_VALUE under a known node name eg `<foo>hash value</foo>`? if so you search is `where extractvalue(xmltype(clob_col), '//foo') = 'hash_value'` (or `/path/to/foo` instead of `//foo` if the absolute path is the same always)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing this:

One uses xml:

```
select id, xml_col 
from t 
where xmlelement(r, xmltype(xml_col)).extract('//HASH_VALUE') is not null;
```

The other is your way:

```
select id, xml_col 
from t 
where xml_col like '%HASH_VALUE%';
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c67ff/1)

Comment: actually i have oracle database. every time i run this query, it gives me 0 results. just to make sure that it will give me any results, i tried the following were xml_col like '*', even that does not give me any results. is this because, data type is clog. can i not search such a data type ?

Comment: In oracle DB you use `'%'` not `'*'`

Comment: when i use '%', it says invalid identifier. ORA-0904

Comment: Can you add to your question the full sql?

Comment: actually, with your help , it is know working. thank you for the help